# sed regex cut string after match

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I tested a regex on http://regexr.com/ and it works like expected.

How can I run this by using `sed`?

```
/^.*?OU=([^,]*)/g
```

The test string looks like:

```
mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455;CN=Mario Test,OU=AT-Test,OU=Tese Sites,DC=Test,DC=local;test.local
```

And the output is:

```
mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455;CN=Mario Test,OU=AT-Test
```

So it should cut the string before the second `OU=` starts.

Thanks

Comment: `sed` doesn't support lazy (non-greedy) matching, which you use in the listed regex (or lookaheads, which can be used to simulate the same). If `grep` is an acceptable alternative, you can use perl regex, which has both.

Comment: both suggestion only prints out AT-Test. but it should cut the string after this match and the substring before should still remain.

Comment: @calabash: Can you show us the _exact_ output needed for your input string in question

Comment: this should be the output: mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455,CN=Mario Test,OU=AT-Test

Comment: Then why did you use a capturing group in the regex? It is used to extract part of the string you need.

Comment: @inian: string is updated.

Comment: @wiktor stribizew: i am not familiar with sed, can you change the cmd to get the right result?

Comment: See http://ideone.com/jrwVoo

Comment: thank you! can you explain what character this stands for "й"?

Comment: It is a temporary char, I used it to insert at the place where the first occurrence of `oU=` is, to be able to remove up to that char during the second step. There should be some control char in fact, I used a Cyrillic letter to for better "visibility".

Comment: thanks for explanation. i have seen that the "OU=" is missing before AT-Linz in your result.

Comment: :) Put it back manually, `sed 's/\([^й]*\)й\([^,]*\).*/\1OU=\2/'`. I updated the above fiddle. Still, I think there must be another way with `awk`. What about `awk -F",OU=" '{print $1 ",OU=" $2}'`?

Comment: works great. as i want to directly change the file with the -i option, i thought sed would be the best solution. thanks!

Comment: I would use `cut -f7 -d';' ` to extract only the field to process (assuming it is always the 7th field) then use `sed` on it.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` is not the best tool for this case when you have to deal with text that contains "columns" and can be split. Here are two possibilities, one with `sed` and the other with `awk`:

```
s="mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455,CN=Mario Test,OU=AT-Linz,OU=Tese Sites,DC=Test,DC=local;test.local"
echo $s | sed 's/OU=/й/' | sed 's/\([^й]*\)й\([^,]*\).*/\1OU=\2/'
echo $s | awk -F",OU=" '{print $1 ",OU=" $2}'
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/JrpOCQ)

The `awk` solution splits with `,OU=`  substring and then joins the first and second column with the separator (since it is hardcoded, it is easy to put it back).

`sed` uses 2 passes: 1) add a non-used char (must be a control char, here, a Cyrillic letter  is used for better "visibility") to mark the border of our match, 2) match all we do not need and match and *capture* what we need to keep with the help of capturing groups and backreferences.

Comment: i will use the awk solution as it far simpler and the better choice when dealing with columns as you wrote. Thanks for explanation.

Comment: is it possible the get this result: mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455;AT-Linz without the CN= part and the OU=

Comment: Try [`awk 'BEGIN { FS = ",OU=|,CN=[^,]*" } { print $1 "," $3 }'`](http://ideone.com/K9WbrE).

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: Glad to help, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: There's no need to introduce cyrilic letters or control characters - `\n` cannot be present in the input so you can just use that. In fact all you'd need for that approach with sed would be `sed 's/OU=/\n/; s/,OU=.*//; s/\n/OU=/'`. In some seds you might need to use backslash followed by a literal newline or `$'\n'` to get a newline character.

Comment: as there are more than one OU, i need to extract the second one, when reading from right to left.

Comment: @calabash: It is easier to get the last one. Use [`sed -E 's/.*,OU=([^,]+).*/\1/'`](https://ideone.com/IVtYPD).

Comment: m.test;mario test;Mario;test;1234;;CN=mario test,OU=Accounting,OU=Dawn,OU=PH-Manila,OU=Sport Sites,DC=sport,DC=local;sport.local/Sport Sites/PH-Manila/Dawn/Accounting/mario test. OU=PH-Manila should be the output

Comment: @calabash The last but one instance can be retrieved with [`sed -E 's/.*,OU=([^,]+).*,OU=.*/\1/'`](https://ideone.com/mskJJJ). But that means there must be at least 2 `,OU=` in the string.

Comment: can you do that with awk (for the second from the right side) as you did it before? the ouptout should look like mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;1234;;PH-Manila

Comment: Ok, but that is still relying on the fact there are at least 2 fields.

Comment: @calabash: Please check if [`awk -F",OU=" '{print $1 ",OU=" $(NF-1)}'`](https://ideone.com/BNkFFz) is doing what you need. `$(NF-1)` gets the last but one column value.

Comment: it is close. the CN field should be disabled, like mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;1234;;PH-Manila

Comment: I am afraid your input and expected output are out of sync, or I am missing something. If you want to remove `CN` fields, do it before `awk`, remove them and that's all. See [`sed 's/;CN=[^,]*/;/g' | awk -F",OU=" '{print $1 $(NF-1)}'](https://ideone.com/53kZH6).

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't clear but from reading your comments, are either of these what you're looking for?

```
$ awk -F, '{print $1 FS $2}' file
mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455;CN=Mario Test,OU=AT-Test

$ awk -F'CN=[^,]+,OU=|,' '{print $1 $2}' file
mario.test;Mario Test;Mario;Test;123;+001122334455;AT-Test
```

Comment: finally this is what i was looking for and had been answered by wiktor before. Thanks for your additional solution.